# Why the input is still asking for another input before it print?

Tags: java

Example:

```
Input:3 4(nextline)  
  5 6 7(nextline)  
  5 6 7
```

It's asking again, so I put the same number for the second time before it prints out. Note I can print any number for the second input. It only accepts the second input.

I don't know what to do please help. Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      
    System.out.println("Input: ");
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    String[] input = line.split(" ");
    if (input.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("Exception Error");
        System.exit(1);
    }
     
    int groupCnt = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
    input = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
    int[][] numbers = new int[groupCnt][];
    if (input.length != groupCnt) {
        System.err.println("Exception Error");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < groupCnt; i++) {
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        numbers[i] = new int[n];
    
    }
    for (int[] number : numbers) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(number));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not mix `nextLinne()` with `nextInt()` or the other `nextXXX` methods. That will not work as you intended it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
    int n = sc.nextInt();
```

to

```
    int n = Integer.parseInt(input[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

In this code you are looping and reading int three times (groupCnt = 3)

```
for (int i = 0; i < groupCnt; i++) {
   int n = sc.nextInt();
   numbers[i] = new int[n];
}
```

So you have to enter 3 times an int.